# Blender Adjust Shape Keys And See Weird Shapes

Tags: shape-keys

I am having fun playing with VRChat models in Blender.

I noticed that when I adjust some of the shape key, some weird shapes will form. It is like the skin is stretched.

How can I fix this or avoid this? I am a new to Blender.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address the raised issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)